Using nested objects with react-hook-form
I am trying to send data to my backend using react-hook-form and this is the FormData interface:
interface FormData {
  title: string;
  // other things
  location: {
    country: string | null;
    city: string | null;
    address: string | null;
  };
}

The problem is that when I submit the form and observe it in my backend (django) it's something like it:
<QueryDict: {'title': ['CCC'], 'location': ['[object Object]']}>

So that the backend will not set location for the object

Edit:
And here there is console log of FormData:
{
    "title": "test",
    "location": {
        "country": "Italy",
        "city": "Milan",
        "address": "Via xx sttembre"
    }
}

also this is the onSubmit() function:
const onSubmit = (data: FieldValues) => {
    const apiClient = new APIClient<FieldValues>("events/");

    apiClient
      .create(formData, { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } })
      .then((res) => {
        setSuccess(true);
        return res.data;
      })
      .catch((err) => setError(err));
    console.log(data);
  };


Can we see the console output of the FormData ? The problem might be in your registration of the location data. Can we see that as well?

It seems like the issue is arising from how I am constructing the FormData object. When I append the nested object location directly to FormData, it's converting it to a string '[object Object]', which isn't what I want.
Instead, I need to handle nested objects separately. Here's how I could adjust my onSubmit() function to correctly handle nested objects:
const onSubmit = (data: FieldValues) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  for (const key in data) {
    if (typeof data[key] === "object" && data[key] !== null) {
      // Handle nested object
      for (const nestedKey in data[key]) {
        const nestedValue = data[key][nestedKey];
        formData.append(`${key}.${nestedKey}`, nestedValue);
      }
    } else {
      formData.append(key, data[key]);
    }
  }

  const apiClient = new APIClient<FieldValues>("events/");

  apiClient
    .create(formData, { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data;
    })
};

